# Virtual host is not accessible outside container using nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Below is my docker-compose.yml file.

I am trying to set reverse proxy.

I tried setting VIRTUAL_HOST and VIRTUAL_PORT Environment to virtual docker containers. it is accessible using Host name and port like http://services.local:81

Please suggest how can I access these services using browser.

I want to access services like http://service1.services.local or http://services.local/service1 Here http://services.local is my default host

**Note:- I am using [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)**

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  prodnetwork:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80" 
    networks:
      - prodnetwork 
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./nginx.tmpl:/app/nginx.tmpl:ro"
      - /etc/nginx/conf.d
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=services.local,localhost

  dockergen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    command: -notify-sighup nginx -watch /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - prodnetwork
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl

  service1:
    build: vgw1
    container_name: service1
    networks:
      - prodnetwork 
    ports:
      - "81:80" 
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=service1.services.local
    expose:
      - "81"

  service2:
    build: vgw2
    container_name: service2
    networks:
      - prodnetwork 
    ports:
      - "82:80" 
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=service2.services.local
    expose:
      - "82"
```

Here vgw1 and vgw2 are two separate dockers which are having Node-Red installed.

Below is **nginx-proxy log**

```
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/01 13:16:59 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 4 containers
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/01 13:16:59 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/01 13:17:09 Error running notify command: nginx -s reload, exit status 1
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/01 13:17:09 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/01 13:17:09 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2017:13:17:51 +0000] "GET /service1 HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx.1    | 2017/09/01 13:17:51 [error] 37#37: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/service1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /service1 HTTP/1.1", host: "services.local"
nginx.1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2017:13:18:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx.1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2017:13:18:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx.1    | 2017/09/01 13:18:49 [error] 37#37: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/service1/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /service1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "services.local"
nginx.1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2017:13:18:49 +0000] "GET /service1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
2017/09/01 13:19:21 [warn] 44#44: server name "services.local/service1" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:74
nginx: [warn] server name "services.local/service1" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:74
2017/09/01 13:19:21 [emerg] 44#44: host not found in upstream "services.local" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:78
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "services.local" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:78
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
dhparam generation complete, reloading nginx
nginx.1    | 2017/09/01 13:23:27 [error] 37#37: *6 "/usr/share/nginx/html/service1/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /service1/ HTTP/1.1", host: "services.local"
nginx.1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2017:13:23:27 +0000] "GET /service1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
Custom dhparam.pem file found, generation skipped
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/04 07:18:19 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 4 containers
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/04 07:18:19 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/04 07:18:19 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2017/09/04 07:18:19 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1    | localhost 172.18.0.1 - - [04/Sep/2017:07:26:42 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 615 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36"
```

**/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: I would have to know what the conf.d looks like and post the output of  `docker logs nginx-proxy`.

Comment: Please have a look. I have updated question with logs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the route that your browser maps too, you are going to have to change the configuration in your `etc/hosts` file. This is virtually telling your browser to look up the DNS records on your local machine for the url that you specify.

There are tools to accomplish this with including [GasMask](https://github.com/2ndalpha/gasmask) (osX) and [Host File Editor](https://github.com/scottlerch/HostsFileEditor) (Windows)

Comment: Do you mean i have to manually configure /etc/hosts file on Ubuntu system. Right?  127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       services.local   127.0.0.1:81       service1.services.local

Comment: Yes. Docker has nothing to do with the DNS lookup on your localhost.

Comment: Whats not working? Are your containers running? Error messages? Is nginx running properly?